# How to display a string with multiple variable in php email

Tags: php

I can't figure out how to display a correct email with this script. It just displays :

Nom : .$nom. Prenom : .$prenom. Compagnie : .$company.

```
<?php 
$nom = $_POST['nom'];
$prenom = $_POST['prenom'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
mail('d.d@shock.be', 'Nouvelle inscription',  'Nom : $nom Prenom :  $prenom Compagnie : $company');
?>
```

Comment: Variable values do not get interpolated when used within single-quotes. Use double-quotes instead. Read more about strings in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use double quotes to replace variables with their values:

```
mail('d.d@shock.be', 'Nouvelle inscription',  "Nom : $nom Prenom :  $prenom Compagnie : $company");
```

See the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php